# c take a slice of an array by advancing the array

Tags: c

I've got an array of binary data in which I need to count the amount of times a certain char sequence appears. 
At the moment I defined a function, to find the index of the 'needle' in the 'haystack'

```
int indexOf(const char *needle, int needleLen, const char *haystack, int haystackLen) { /.../ }
```

It returns `-1` if the needle can't be found, otherwise it returns the index.

The next step is to run `indexOf` in a `while`-loop (till we get `-1`) to get the count.

My question is: whenever I found an index in `haystack`, how do I take a slice of `haystack` where the first char's determined by `indexOf` have been chomped off?

Example:
My haystack is `hello_world`, the needle is `o`.
`indexOf` will return `4`.
How do I take a slice of `hello world` without the first `4` chars?
E.g. I want `_world`

Comment: No offence to your `indexOf` function, but why not use [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)?

Comment: Indeed strstr doesn't work with binary data, also if an \0 occurs, it won't look any further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My haystack is hello_world, the needle is o. indexOf will return 4. How do I take a slice of hello world without the first 4 chars? E.g. I want _world

If the index is 4, you need to skip the first 5 characters (remember indexing in C is 0 based).

That would be `haystack + 4 + 1`. Just remember to update the size of `haystack` accordingly, so as to not access off the end it.

Or in C:

```
idx = indexOf(needle, needleLEn, haystack + idx + 1, haystackLen - idx - 1);
```

Where if `idx` is 4, it will look from index 5 onward.

Comment: Can you give an example in c code?
`newHaystack = haystack + 4 + 1` ?

Comment: So the next call to indexOf would be `indexOf(needle, needleLEn, haystack + 4 + 1, haystackLen - 4 - 1)`

Comment: @Seneca - added. And thanks to JeremyP for the template.

Comment: as it stands, wouldn't `idx` have to start at -1 for this to start searching from the start of the data though?

Comment: @ChrisTurner - I don't know. I haven't seen how the OP setup the loop they talked about. Personally I would have thrown out the ptr + length  approach and used pairs of pointers to define the ranges of data. Would have reduced the amount of arithmetic and special index values to keep track of.

Comment: I don't know much C, so the approach above is probably very naive. I'm trying to replace a node script which replaces text (multiple occurences) in a file containing binary data. (strstr doesn't work for my use case). The overhead of starting a node process is so extreme, I'm trying it C. Maybe I should take the time to fully learn C.

Comment: @Seneca - Learning C is always a good thing to do. And strongly suggest to move onto the pointer based approach, like strstr does. It may seem a bit daunting to re-write the function. But using it will become much simpler. You won't have to recalculate the length for instance. A rough draft will look like this http://ideone.com/ko7GQY Pardon the misuse of sizeof, it's just a quick and dirty example.